# A sugestão de "Perguntas que talvez já têm sua resposta" pode ser melhorada?

Tags: novo-recurso, perguntas-duplicadas, pesquisa

Notei hoje esta pergunta (que por sinal já esta fechada):

- [Quando devo usar let ou var em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/294022/3635)

Eu já sabia que existia uma pergunta que abordava o assunto, então pensei que talvez o autor tivesse ignorado as sugestões de busca, então por curiosidade fui tentar criar uma pergunta com o mesmo titulo, deveria supostamente aparecer esta pergunta na listagem:

- [Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando let e var?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/3635)

Mas não foi o que ocorreu, o resultado foi este (ignorem o primeiro que é do proprio autor):

> [image: sugestões de perguntas com respostas]

Aqui esta a lista toda que retornou:

- [Quando devo usar ModelState.IsValid?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136184/3635)
- [Quando devo usar ou não o new?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104177/3635)
- [Quando devo usar o ConstraintLayout?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192729/3635)
- [Quando devo usar a tag </img> ou a propriedade do CSS background?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190527/3635)
- [Pra que usar VAR em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211652/3635)
- [Quando devo usar o atributo class nos elementos HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117922/3635)
- [Quando devo usar o operador "?" em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92101/3635)
- [Quando devo usar empty ou isset?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91243/3635)
- [Quando devo usar __init__ em funções dentro de classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109013/3635)
- [Quando devo usar GC.SuppressFinalize()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102609/3635)
- [Quando devo usar Data URI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21736/3635)
- [Devo usar um gerador de parser ou devo desenvolver meu próprio código para fazer "parse" e "lex"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2130/3635)
- [Quando devo usar função GET e quando devo usar função POST?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118213/3635)
- [Quando devo usar um patch?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148309/3635)
- [Quando usar listas e quando usar tuplas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192727/3635)
- [Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/3635)
- [AngularJS - Quando devo utilizar ng-show e quando devo utilizar ng-hide?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111312/3635)
- [Quando usar this e quando usar event.target](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63395/3635)
- [Quando usar var em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/3635)
- [Quando eu devo usar mipmaps?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154399/3635)
- [dúvida sobre functions em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70542/3635)
- [Quando usar uma unique constraints vs indices únicos no Oracle?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/515/3635)
- [Quando devo usar campos desabilitados, somente leitura ou escondidos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147014/3635)
- [Quando usar método assíncronos ou síncronos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201998/3635)

Notem que não foi retornado a esperada:

- [Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando let e var?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/3635)

Eu não sei dizer se palavras como "var" ou "let" são ignoradas, ou se o sistema tem variações e como quase tudo as vezes precisa de melhorias

Isto pode ser melhorado?

Comment: Também sempre me perguntei o porquê dessas perguntas não serem ordenadas pela quantidade de votos. Ao meu ver, se é relacionada e bem votada, deveria aparecer no topo como leitura obrigatória do AP.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss nesse ponto eu concordo parcialmente, assim acho que votos sim deve ser levados em conta, mas o problema é que mesmo a busca sendo o mais precisa que for ainda sim haverão semelhantes e isto poderia causar confusão, deixando a que serve como resposta abaixo da de interesse, pessoalmente acho tendo resposta com um upvote no total ou aceita e que o titulo "case" bem então deve ficar no topo :)

Comment: A impressão que sempre tenho é que pesquisam no Google, pegam os últimos resultados em relevância e mostram :) tem coisas que é melhor não reinventar a roda, se é pra fazer o próprio, precisa fazer bem feito.

Comment: Considerando que agora tem a duplicata com esse ótimo título, acho que ela merece uns upvotes. Não sei o critério que o sistema usa para ordenar as sugestões, mas votos podem/devem ajudar. Eu mesclei a pergunta com a duplicata esperando que isso causasse algum tipo de redirect, mas parece que não. Estranho, eu tinha certeza que tinha algo assim.

Comment: @bfavaretto por incrivel que pareça, suspeito que sejam as aspas, editei o titulo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/47165/revisions vou aguardar um tempo (cache do servidor) e vou tentar criar uma pergunta com titulo semelhante.

Answer (score 2):

A funcionalidade é basicamente uma pesquisa, e não dá "boost" nenhum a perguntas com melhor pontuação ou melhores respostas — portanto os títulos mais semelhantes vão aparecer sempre em cima. Se experimentares utilizar um título diferente, os resultados são *drasticamente* diferentes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro, a funcionalidade podia funcionar melhor (ver [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225200/208518) e [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335166/1328704)), mas não é um bug.

Comment: Verdade, não é um [meta-tag:bug], ainda sim ao meu ver pode e precisa ser melhorado. Eu gostaria de deixar em aberto como sugestão, se você concordar.

Comment: Se quiseres alterar ligeiramente a publicação para ser um pedido de novo recurso, tudo bem :)

Comment: Feito! Obrigado.